# what is the use of git remote set-head

Tags: git, github

What is the use of setting the origin/HEAD using the `git remote set-head` command, if it is only a local reference? I read somewhere that it is the branch checked out by default when we clone, but how does that work if it's only local?

Comment: [Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-headem):

“Having a default branch for a remote is not required, but allows the name of the remote to be specified in lieu of a specific branch. For example, if the default branch for origin is set to master, then origin may be specified wherever you would normally specify origin/master.”

Comment: Posted as an answer given that you suggested that the excerpt satisfied your inquiry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-headem):

> Having a default branch for a remote is not required, but allows the
> name of the remote to be specified in lieu of a specific branch. For
> example, if the default branch for origin is set to master, then
> origin may be specified wherever you would normally specify
> origin/master.